# Flex: changing value in an array where elements are objects

Tags: apache-flex, arrays

Example:

```
var arr_1:Array = new Array();
arr_1.push({sdate:"2010-02-02",status:"New"});
arr_1.push({sdate:"2010-02-03",status:"New"});
arr_1.push({sdate:"2010-02-04",status:"New"});
arr_1.push({sdate:"2010-02-05",status:"New"});
```

How can i change element number 3 status to: "Old", without removing it. just update the status value??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr_1[3].status = "Old";
```

Keep in mind, though, that this is a 0 (zero) based array, so the index `3` will be the 4th element in the array.